# How to know what item in state changed in useeffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

useeffect is run on each rerender to prevent that i pass an empty array

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[])
```

And to fire useeffect on state change of let's say count state variable

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[count])
```

And if i have more of  one state variable

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[count, somethingelse])
```

My question is how to know which state variable caused the firing on useeffect hook

EDIT:

For people who are still checking this
You can just do the following
you can have multiple useEffect function

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[count])
```

this will fire when count will change

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[somethingelse])
```

this will fire when somethingelse will change

Answer (score -3):

So the useEffect is run when the state changes, you will definitely know what is the value of the state.
For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
if(count){
  ...code
}
} , [count, somethingelse])
```

So basically you can add conditions to check if the value of the state is your desired value and run the desired code then.

Comment: my question is which one caused the useffect function to fire

Comment: There is no inbuilt api provided by react itself to know that. Instead what we usually do is we just check the states in the useEffect if it is the desired value, only then the code for that state runs.
Also, there are more elegant solutions provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187563/determine-which-dependency-array-variable-caused-useeffect-hook-to-fire