# How to debug "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded" in React

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I get it. A `useEffect` is calling a `setState` that triggers the same `useEffect` again, creating an infinite loop.

My question is: What is the best way to debug this situation? Is there a way to track *which* specific properties or state variables were the ones that triggered a `useEffect` callback?

Comment: Please add a code example. You could start removing items from the dependency array so the use effect wouldn't be called again.

Comment: This answer is very helpful in this context
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187563/determine-which-dependency-array-variable-caused-useeffect-hook-to-fire#answer-59843241

Comment: Thanks. That question and answer are indeed what I was looking for. I have voted to mark this question as duplicate of that one